# Flutter - How to use a FadeTransition inside a StreamBuilder?

Tags: animation, flutter, dart

I am trying to make a colour transition animation inside a StreamBuilder which is inside a stateless widget. I have no idea how to perform that since all the examples and tutorials about this subject use a Stateful Widget.

I thought about using FadeTransition Widget but and maybe store the state in my Bloc that controls that view.

Please give me any suggestions if you have, Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

To perform a fade in transition in a streambuilder, it's easy, simply use a widget called [AnimatedSwitcher](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html) :

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
  builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
    return AnimatedSwitcher(
      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
      child: _getMainWidget(snapshot, context),
    );
  },
);
}
```

Here we use an [AnimatedSwitcher](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html) to animate a transition when the child of the AnimatedSwitcher change's, the default animation is a fade animation, but you could add your custom animation by passing the widget a [TransitionBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TransitionBuilder.html) as an argument

Comment: Thank you for your answer , I will mark it as correct as soon as i try it :D